# flutter - Call function on rotate

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to call a function after user rotates device? I need to hide the AppBar after the device is rotated.

I tried SystemChrome DeviceOrientation.portraip methots but it's not works automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `OrientationBuilder`. It lets you rebuild its child Widgets on rotation.

```
OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 3 : 4,
    );
  },
);
```